# why cant i split at "|" in clojure

Tags: regex, clojure

I am trying to split a string in *clojure* "`Hello|World`" but when use the split method "`(clojure.string/split x #"|")`" I get a weird result, I get this `"[h e l l o | w o r l d]"`. Can anyone tell me why it does this and how can I split it up to get `[hello world]`?

Comment: Use `(clojure.string/split "Hello|World"  (re-pattern (. java.util.regex.Pattern quote "|")))` which 1) invokes `Pattern.quote` to create a Pattern from the string "|", then 2) uses `re-pattern` to create a regular expression from the quoted string, which is then passed  as the second argument to `clojure.string/split`, which then produces the desired result `["Hello" "World"]`. If you want to make this a bit prettier use `(defn re-quoted-pattern [s] (re-pattern (. java.util.regex.Pattern quote s)))`, and your code then becomes `(clojure.string/split "Hello|World" (re-quoted-pattern "|"))`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - if you could please remove your close vote on this I could post the comment above as an answer. You may be correct that from a Java point of view the question is a dup, but this question is not tagged for [tag:java], and from a Clojure point of view no one has addressed the issue of how to invoke `Pattern.quote` from Clojure; thus, I believe your close-as-duplicate should be undone. Thanks.

Comment: This is a question tagged with `regex`. The `|` symbol is a well-known char that requires escaping if one wants to treat is as a literal char. No need to reopen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
(str/split "Hello|World" #"|")  => ["H" "e" "l" "l" "o" "|" "W" "o" "r" "l" "d"]
(str/split "Hello World" #" ")  => ["Hello" "World"]
(str/split "Hello|World" #"\|") => ["Hello" "World"]
```

In a regular expression, the `|` character is special, and needs to be escaped with a backslash `\`.

The `|` character is a logical operator in regex and is normally used to mean "or", like "abc|def":

```
(str/split "Hello|World" #"e|o") => ["H" "ll" "|W" "rld"]
```

Since you had nothing else present it seems to have been interpreted as "anything OR anything", so it matched the boundary between each character.

[See the Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information.